# What does Allen's comment about "You've Got Mail" mean?

Tags: the-other-guys

When Terry goes to Allen's home, they talk about the movie She's Got Mail (You've Got Mail) casting Tom Hanks and Meg Ryan. Allen said Tom Hanks have poison ivy up his ass. What's he talking about?

Comment: Er, maybe that's what's funny, because it's *not* what happened in that film at all and has nothing to do with the way *they* met.

Comment: Oh, that was a great line *because* that weird poison ivy stuff was absolutely *not* in that Tom Hanks film. I couldn't stop loughing at this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line from the movie is:

> It was like that movie where Meg Ryan meets that guy with poison ivy in his ass... I'll think of the name later...

This comparison is a [dissimile](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dissimile), presumably added as a joke - there was no poison ivy in *You've Got Mail* and this is covered later when they remember the name of the movie:

> "She's Got Mail", that's the name of the movie. - That's it!
>
> With Tom Hanks? - And Meg Ryan. - He didn't have poison ivy up his ass.

Comment: You said, `this is covered later when they remember the name of the movie` but after your quote, Allen and Sheila say "oh yes he did (yes he did)… way up there".  So I don't think your example applies